# Android ListView example crashes. Can't start app

Tags: android, listview, layout

I spent quite some time trying to apply what I learn but whenever I run this example on my phone, it just crashes.

What i was trying to make is just a ImageView with 2 textview on the right just like how the contacts look on the phone.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    names = res.getStringArray(R.array.contacts);
    info = res.getStringArray(R.array.descript);
    int [] images = {R.drawable.pic0, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4};

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this,names,images,info);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);



}
class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    int[] pictures;
    String[] conArray;
    String[] infoArray;
    myAdapter(Context c,String[] contacts, int images[],String[] descript){

        super(c,R.layout.single_row,R.id.textView,contacts);
        this.context = c;
        this.pictures=images;
        this.conArray=contacts;
        this.infoArray=descript;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView des = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        image.setImageResource(pictures[position]);
        name.setText(conArray[position]);
        des.setText(infoArray[position]);

        return v;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change this `ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)` to `ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView)`. Similarly others. Also consider using a view holder.

Answer (score 2):

Change in `getView(....)`

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
 TextView des = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

to

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
TextView des = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

find a `View` from inflated rootview.

and also used `View Holder pattern` for smooth scrolling http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: Thanks it worked. Was the problem due to having too much findViewById which is quite an intensive task itself?

Answer (score 0):

Check the array length are equal

```
Resources res = getResources();
names = res.getStringArray(R.array.contacts);
info = res.getStringArray(R.array.descript);
int [] images = {R.drawable.pic0, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2,R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4};
```

**contact** string array and **names** String array should be equal to **int[] images**